# Trying to add a field with powershell throws an error

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, xsd, metadata, field

When i'm trying to add a new field, with type Taxonomy (Managed Metadata) via powershell with the method : AddFieldAsXml, It throw me an error :

```
Error while adding field :  Exception calling "AddFieldAsXml" with "1" argument(s): "The object has been updated by another user since it was last fetched."
```

The weird thing is that I'm adding the field so it can't have been modified or updated by another user ! Can it ?

If you have ideas ? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this stuff in a foreach cycle?

Comment: Seeing actual code is generally helpful if you would like to get a good answer.